# AS3 Draggable layer/mask on y axis

Tags: image, actionscript-3, draggable, mask, movieclip

I'd like to create this exact example: http://www.nytimes.com/2008/12/28/nyregion/18thennow.html?_r=2&
however have the drag occur on the y axis instead of the x. I was working with some basic code, but wondering how to lock it in place?

```
myImage.mask = myMask;
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, fMouseDown);
 stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fMouseUp);
function fMouseDown(e:MouseEvent):void {
 myMask.startDrag();
 }
 function fMouseUp(e:MouseEvent):void {
 myMask.stopDrag();
 }
```

It isn't quite what I need though, any help? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The documentation of startDrag()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Sprite.html#startDrag%28%29) tells you about a second optional parameter `bounds`:

> **bounds**:Rectangle (default = null) — Value relative to the coordinates of the Sprite's parent that specify a constraint rectangle for the Sprite.

The y axis is a rectangle with zero width.

In order to drag both the handle and the mask, put both into a container `Sprite` object. This should be the object you call `startDrag` and `stopDrag` on.
But as you only want to initiate the dragging if the handle was pressed (and not the entire mask), register the listener for the mouse event on the handler.

Comment: I did actually read it, these forums: smh.. if I wasn't confused I wouldn't ask for more examples. Can this rectangle be set to just be the stage boundaries, or would I just enter those same values as the stage dimension. I see how the boundary box being set, but I don't see how it's applied to the mask. Did you actually look at the example I posted as to what I'm trying to do? Just curious - thanks for any help....

Comment: "A bit more of an example" is simply to broad of a question. Yes, it's clear that you are confused, but without stating what exactly you are confused about, it's very hard to help. The rectangle can be set to whatever you want it to be. I provided a suggestion on how to achieve the desired limitation of movement along the y axis in my answer. Does this allow you to move the handle in the desired way? Yes, I looked at the link, but I need more information on how you set up the mask. How did you create the handle and the mask?

Comment: Sorry for not enough clarity/information. And I thank you for the link - I'm unclear as to how to create just the handle as the drag point rather than the entire mask. (i didn't create the example in the NY times link) I basically was hoping to recreate exactly what was in the example link, but got as far as one draggable mask over another static image.

Comment: Now it's me who got a bit confused over this answer, but I think I got it now. To make just the handle the drag point, register the listener for the mouse event only on the handle, but start the drag on both (the mask and the handle). this can be achieved by putting both into a container. I added that to my answer.

Comment: I apologize for my density here, but can you show me a coded example with what i have? Or is my code example way off base? Thanks for your time!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70177/discussion-between-user2561920-and-null).

Comment: Actually I've figured it out myself - thanks for your help - I just had to re read the adobe pages a bunch of times - :)